# Wordpress get_transient() returning an encoded string sometimes instead of array

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, widget, transient

I have been trying to make a custom twitter widget which displays the last few tweets from multiple feeds. Each feed creates an instance of the following Class:

```
<?php

class Foo{
  protected $name = '';

  //opts
  protected $numTweets = 3;
  protected $transName = ''; // Name of value in database.
  protected $backupName = '';
  protected $cacheTime = 5; // Time in minutes between updates.
  protected $exclude_replies = true; // Leave out @replies?

  public function __construct( $username ){
    $this->name = $username;
    $this->transName = 'jctft3' . $username;
    $this->backupName = 'jctfb3' . $username;
  }

  public function get_feed(){
    $feed = get_transient( $this->transName );

    // Do we already have saved tweet data? If not, lets get it.
    if( $feed === false  ){
      $feed = $this->call_twitter();
    }

    $html = $this->build_html( $feed );

    return $html;
  }// protected function get_feed(){...}

  protected function call_twitter(){
    /* We need the following:

    $feed = array(
      'username' => '',
      'friendly_name' => '',
      'url' => ''

      'tweets' => array(
        array(
          'html' => '',
          'url' => '',
          'time' => ''
        ),
        array(
          'html' => '',
          'url' => '',
          'time' => ''
        )
      )
    );
    */
    $feed = array();

    // Get the tweets from Twitter.
    $response = wp_remote_get( "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$this->name}&count=10&exclude_replies=false" );

    // parse Twitter response into an array
    if( !is_wp_error($response) && $response[ 'response' ][ 'code' ] == 200 ){
      // Get tweets into an array.
      $tweets_json = json_decode( $response['body'], true );
      // Now update the array to store just what we need.
      $feed[ 'username' ] = $tweets_json[ 0 ][ 'user' ][ 'screen_name' ];
      $feed[ 'friendly_name' ] = $tweets_json[ 0 ][ 'user' ][ 'name' ];
      $feed[ 'url' ] = 'https://twitter.com/' . $tweets_json[ 0 ][ 'user' ][ 'screen_name' ];
      $feed[ 'tweets' ] = array();

      foreach ( $tweets_json as $tweet ){
        $my_tweet = array();

        // Core info.
        $my_tweet[ 'url' ] = 'http://twitter.com/#!/'. $feed[ 'username' ] .'/status/'. $tweet['id_str'];
        // Message. Convert links to real links.
        $pattern = '/http:(\S)+/';
        $replace = '<a href="${0}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">${0}</a>';
        $my_tweet[ 'html' ] = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $tweet['text'] );
        //$my_tweet[ 'html' ] = $tweet['text'];
        // Need to get time in Unix format.
        $time = $this->twitter_time( $tweet[ 'created_at' ] );
        //$time = date_parse( $time );
        //$uTime = mktime($time['hour'], $time['minute'], $time['second'], $time['month'], $time['day'], $time['year']);
        $my_tweet[ 'time' ] = $time;

        array_push( $feed[ 'tweets' ], $my_tweet );
      }

      // Save our new transient, and update the backup.
      set_transient( $this->transName, $feed, 60 * $this->cacheTime );
      update_option( $this->backupName, $feed );
    }
    else{
      // i.e. Fetching new tweets failed.
      $feed = get_option( $this->backupName ); // False if there has never been data saved.
    }

    return $feed;
  }

  protected function build_html( $feed ){
    $html = '';

    $is_top = false;
    if( $feed[ 'friendly_name' ] == 'Johnny Cupcakes' ){
      $is_top = true;
    }

    ob_start();
    include(  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../html/feed.html' );
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    return $html;
  }

}

?>
```

The first time the plugin builds the html ( that is, when the data is being pulled directly from twitter and not from data stored in our local database ), everything displays fine. However, when I use get_transient() to retrieve the cached data, on some of the tweets (which tweet generates this error and how many tweets refuse to function varies) I get the following error:

```
Warning:  Illegal string offset 'username' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/wp-johnnycupcakes/wp-content/plugins/jc-twitter-widget/html/feed.html on line 12
```

Line 12 of feed.html is:

```
<h3><a target="_new" href="<?php echo $feed[ 'url' ]; ?>"> @<?php echo $feed[ 'username' ]; ?> </a></h3>
```

Upon further investigation, it seems like sometimes on some of my feeds, when I use get_transient(), the value returned is no longer an array, but an encoded string ( which I'm assuming is Wordpress's encoding convention for storing transient_values in the database ). The string looks like this:

```
string(830) "a:4:{s:8:"username";s:15:"JHNYCPKS_London";s:13:"friendly_name";s:18:"Johnny Cupcakes UK";s:3:"url";s:35:"https://twitter.com/JHNYCPKS_London";s:6:"tweets";a:9:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"url";s:63:"http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_London/status/278196905350164480";s:4:"html";s:128:"Baked in USA long sleeve, Truffle and White Mens Basic Tee's are now back in stock come and grab them now while supplies last!!!";s:4:"time";s:11:"2 hours ago";}i:1;a:3:{s:3:"url";s:63:"http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_London/status/278180246967173121";s:4:"html";s:121:"Put a pin on it! @ Johnny Cupcakes http://t.co/nxVSAG63";s:4:"time";s:11:"4 hours ago";}i:2;a:3:{s:3:"url";s:63:"http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_London/status/278179975474053120";s:4:"html";s:161:"Big kid magnet came in today! "
```

When an array is returned (and thus the feed is successfully displayed), it looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(15) "JHNYCPKS_Boston"
  ["friendly_name"]=>
  string(20) "JohnnyCupcakesBoston"
  ["url"]=>
  string(35) "https://twitter.com/JHNYCPKS_Boston"
  ["tweets"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/278204808756862976"
      ["html"]=>
      string(139) "IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING! IT'S RAINING!"
      ["time"]=>
      string(11) "2 hours ago"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/278169219160489984"
      ["html"]=>
      string(167) "Four #freshlybaked keychains were released this weekend! Which is your favorite? <a href="http://t.co/Xn16NsjU" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://t.co/Xn16NsjU</a>"
      ["time"]=>
      string(11) "4 hours ago"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/278137791391617025"
      ["html"]=>
      string(29) "@thatkidTHILL good luck, man!"
      ["time"]=>
      string(11) "6 hours ago"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/278137703281881088"
      ["html"]=>
      string(96) "@dcachopa18 i don't think so, sorry! we'll let you know if we do. what size are you looking for?"
      ["time"]=>
      string(11) "6 hours ago"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/277888036237373440"
      ["html"]=>
      string(188) "Only a few hours left! Spend $50, get a $10 gift card. Stop in or shop online. We close at 7 tonight! <a href="http://t.co/082T5jTf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://t.co/082T5jTf</a>"
      ["time"]=>
      string(12) "23 hours ago"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/277786268274933760"
      ["html"]=>
      string(135) "Here's the new Boston in-store! cc: @b3asTTw33ts <a href="http://t.co/soLoEYqv" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://t.co/soLoEYqv</a>"
      ["time"]=>
      string(9) "yesterday"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(3) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(63) "http://twitter.com/#!/JHNYCPKS_Boston/status/277526406076968961"
      ["html"]=>
      string(119) "What's everyone's favorite piece from this release?! The new Boston exclusive seems to be the hot ticket. #freshlybaked"
      ["time"]=>
      string(9) "yesterday"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a couple ideas about what could be causing this:

- Trying to store too much data into a transient
- Some character that's getting pulled in is messing up either how Wordpress converts data into a string or vice versa.

Does anyone have some experience with this issue and could point me in the right direction for correcting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is going awry with the [serialisation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) of your array; the sample encoded string you show is only a partial serialisation of your array, so it's slipped up somewhere (either in serialising, or in saving to the DB).

Maybe try serialising it yourself (call [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)), [base64-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) it, and then set the transient. On retrieval, [base64-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php), and [deserialise](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). It just might work, if the problem is with WordPress / wpdb saving the serialised array.

Comment: Another possible fix is to json_encode() your array, and json_decode() on retrieval, as per [this comment on the man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#92284).

Comment: You rock, it worked. To store my data I just used serialize(), base64_encode() ,then set_transient(). To retrieve, I used get_transient(), base64_decode(), then, unseralize().